# Functional component: can't access variables from the handleSubmit function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd greatly appreciate if someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong here; I can't access any of the variables declared below, from neither the handleSubmit or testOnChange functions. What am I missing?

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import useGlobal from './store';

const BasicTextFields = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {rowId} = useParams();
  const [globalState, globalActions] = useGlobal();
  const testVar = 55;

  const selectedOfficeListRow = globalState.officeList.find(i => i.id === parseInt(rowId));

  const handleSubmit = (event) => { 
    alert(rowId);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const testOnChange = (event) => {
    alert(21);
  };  

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="sm">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign up
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="firstName"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                autoFocus
                defaultValue={selectedOfficeListRow.town}
                onChange={testOnChange}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign Up
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Container>

  );
}

export default BasicTextFields;
```

Comment: What exactly does "can't access any of the variables" mean? Is it throwing an error? Are they undefined? Which variables are you referring to?

Comment: If you're alerting `undefined` when you submit, then you don't have a url parameter that's being picked up by your routing module. However, you should be getting an alert with the number 21 every time you change something in the textfield.

Comment: @jmargolisvt - No you don't.  `() => handleSubmit(e)` would also not pass the event.

Comment: @BrianThompson yes, they're undefined. Sorry should've made it clearer, and was just about to define them. I've tried just via name, and via this, e.g. testVar and this.testVar - neither works

Comment: Event is passed correctly to both functions, I've tested it.

Comment: @ark - What does `console.log(rowId)` show when put just before the return?

Comment: rowId in fact works @technicallynick, but I need the globalState, globalActions which are undefined. Also neither does the testVar work.

Comment: Please create a reproducible example. Without one I don't know that this can be answered. `testVar` is in scope and should work.

Comment: Can you post the imports and Button details ?

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa I've edited the answer.

Comment: Can you try onClick for Button ?

Comment: Ok...so the issue seems to have evolved. What specific variable is not working in the `handleSubmit` function? Could it actually be `selectedOfficeListRow`? That seems to be a custom hook that likely leads to a redux like store? Since this value isn't memoized, it's recalculated every time, and it may not be done calculating by the time the rerender/submit occurs.

Comment: As a number of folks have said here, without a working example there is not much we can do here.  I have posted a working codesandbox with minor modifications.  Please make some edits to that to match your actual example:  https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-turing-1dvbw?file=/src/App.js:0-1710

Comment: Please see my comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [simplified working version](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-turing-1dvbw?file=/src/App.js) of your code.  Everything appears to work.  Compare your code to that:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  Button,
  Container,
  CssBaseline,
  Grid,
  TextField,
  Typography
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const BasicTextFields = () => {
  const { rowId } = useParams();
  const testVar = 55;

  const selectedOfficeListRow = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }].find(
    (i) => i.id === parseInt(rowId)
  );

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log(rowId, testVar);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="sm">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign up
        </Typography>
        <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="fname"
                name="firstName"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                autoFocus
                defaultValue={selectedOfficeListRow.town}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">
            Sign Up
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:rowId" component={BasicTextFields} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: After restarting the application, it started working. It's running a watch, and it was picking up the code changes, so didn't think it needed a reboot.

Marking your answer as correct one, since I appreciate your effort.